# Use Slash Commands in all servers where have a bot without GuildID (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

slash command require guild_ids but how to make that it run without it(discord.py)
and I am using `discord_slash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

discord.py has been discontinued, try pycord or another fork of discord.py that is updated